# Wordpress Enqueueing Scripts Load Time

Tags: performance, wordpress

I am writing a Wordpress shortcodes plugin for a client and admittedly don't know much about load times.  Which would load faster, one enqueued script with a size of 300kb or 10 separate enqueued scripts with a total size of 150kb (about 30kb each)?

So another way to ask this question would be, 'does it take a noticeable amount of time to enqueue a script in Wordpress?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enqueuing is not the bottleneck, the HTTP overhead is it. Combine and minify those scripts. Make sure they are compressed.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of enqueueing to make it so there is only 1 HTTP request made after all of the scripts are enqueued?  Again, this is definitely not my area of expertise.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: **Concatenation** is only possible if you use `wp_enqueue_script()` but it is not the default behavior. Some plugins (like W3 Total Cache) can do that. Enqueueing exists to manage dependencies and to allow plugins to filter the script URIs.

Comment: So if I used wp_enqueue_script() to enqueue 10 scripts, would it load as one single HTTP request or 10 separate requests?  Or would it only load as one single HTTP request if I had W3 Total Cache enabled?  Thanks again.

Comment: By default: 10 separate requests.